# how to adda drop-down box to the basic info page of publisher portal?

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I have wso2am4.0.0 and run success.
I want to change the textbox to drop down box of the Roles of basic info page (https://localhost:9443/publisher, Develop > Basic Info) , like image below.
[image]

How do I modify the source code of carbon-apimgt to make this change?

Comment: You may achieve this through the Publisher UI customizations: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/customize-product/customizations/overriding-the-publisher-portal-theme/

Answer (score 0):

The publisher portal code can be found here - https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/tree/v9.0.174/features/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.publisher.feature

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it's not possible. For that, you need to populate the existing roles list. Current publisher Rest API does not have such a resource to populate the role list and it only contains a validation resource[1].

[1] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/product-apis/publisher-apis/publisher-v2/publisher-v2/#tag/Roles